# Populate StopDate when Id is changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is causing multiple instances of the same account. Currently it looks something like this:

```
CaptureDate: Id       Account  BeginDate  StopDate
20150324 :   1234607  :1234    :20150324  :null

CaptureDate:20170425 Id: 12334607 Account:1234 BeginDate:20170425 stopDate:null
```

To prevent multiple instances of the same account I want to give the first record a StopDate of the next records start date. in this instance the stopDate should be 20170425. How can I do this?

Comment: Before you do anything else you should change your datatype to be a date instead of the string or varchar you currently have. Then you can easily do this with a recursive cte.

Comment: @SeanLange can I please get an example

Comment: Do you need to actually store the Stop Date, or could you work it out on the fly by finding the next BeginDate for the same ID?

Comment: @GarethD I would like to store it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want `lead()` with an `update`?

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, lead(begindate) over (partition by id order by begindate) as next_begindate
      from t
     )
update tupdate
     set stopdate = next_begindate
     where stopdate is null and next_begindate is not null;
```